# Error while installing ROS : gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, failed-installation

xyz@ubuntu:~$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

getting this error while installing ROS noetic in ubuntu 20.04.5, arm64, UTM

Tried few steps but didn't worked

Comment: Are you behind Proxy network?

Comment: Can you post what steps you already tried, so that we can suggest some more?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because apt is not able to receive trusted security key. So you can manually add the key using the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

This fetches the key directly to trusted keys. And then you can continue to use `sudo apt update` to get the package and continue the process of installation.

This [site](https://vprivalov.medium.com/ubuntu-tips-fix-error-with-security-keys-in-apt-update-e958616e0650) helped me resolve the same issue I faced.